# Recover the do notation syntax

Tags: haskell

I was reading through [Scrap your type classes](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/05/scrap-your-type-classes.html). This provides an alternatives for type classes. However, I was stuck with a comment by [Paul Chiusano](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/05/scrap-your-type-classes.html?showComment=1338305803531#c5117471807774445845) which talked about recovering the *do notation* syntax.

Frankly I could not understand how

```
return :: a -> (Monad f -> f a) 
(>>=) :: (Monad f -> f a) -> (a -> (Monad f -> f b)) -> (Monad f -> f b)
```

would help recover *do notation*

> You can implement all the monadic combinators like this, and desugar
>   do notation to them. The do block evaluates to a function that accepts
>   the monad dictionary, so you can even conveniently write code that's
>   polymorphic in the choice of monad, without having to thread the
>   dictionary around manually.

And especially, how it would fit int he context of GADT style approach mentioned in the above article?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> {-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types, RebindableSyntax #-}
>
> import qualified Prelude
> import qualified System.IO
> import Prelude (String, ($), (++))
> import System.IO (IO)
> ```

With Gabriel Gonzales' suggestion

> ```
> data MonadI f = MonadI {
>     _return :: forall a . a -> f a,
>     _bind :: forall a b . f a -> (a -> f b) -> f b
> }
> ```

you could implement the necessary functions `return` and `(>>=)` as follows, with the types as suggested by Paul Chiusano:

> ```
> return :: a -> (MonadI f -> f a)
> return x = \dict -> (_return dict) x
>
> (>>=) :: (MonadI f -> f a) -> (a -> (MonadI f -> f b)) -> (MonadI f -> f b)
> ma >>= f = \dict -> (_bind dict) (ma dict) (\x -> f x dict)
> ```

This is not enough to recover do-notation, because you'll also need `(>>)` and ([sadly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761302/why-were-haskell-98s-standard-classes-made-inferior-to-haskell-1-3s)) `fail`. You can implement them as follows:

> ```
> (>>) :: (MonadI f -> f a) -> (MonadI f -> f b) -> (MonadI f -> f b)
> ma >> mb = ma >>= (\_ -> mb)
>
> fail :: String -> MonadI f -> f a
> fail str = \_ -> Prelude.error str -- Because let's not further entertain that idea.
> ```

And now we have the required facilities to write simple programs:

> ```
> main :: IO ()
> main = (\m -> m monad'IO) $ do
>     putStrLn "What is your name?"
>     name <- getLine
>     putStrLn $ "Hello, " ++ name
> ```

Of course, we're going to have to borrow some things from `System.IO` for that:

> ```
> getLine :: MonadI IO -> IO String
> getLine = \_ -> System.IO.getLine
>
> putStrLn :: String -> (MonadI IO -> IO ())
> putStrLn str = \_ -> System.IO.putStrLn str
>
> monad'IO :: MonadI IO
> monad'IO = MonadI {
>     _return = (Prelude.return :: a -> IO a),
>     _bind = ((Prelude.>>=) :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b)
> }
> ```